# Proving for every simple graph $G$ with maximum degree at most 3 and at least 4 vertices, $k'(G) = k(G)$.

Tags: graph-theory, proof-explanation

**Prove that for every simple graph G with maximum degree at most 3 and at least 4 vertices, $k'(G) = k(G)$.**

I am still relatively new to the definitions of $k(G)$ and $k'(G)$. So far my understanding is that $k(G)$ is the number of vertices, $|s|$, removed from $G$ so that $G - s$ is disconnected, and $k'(G)$ is the number of edges, say $|f|$, removed from $G$ so that $G - f$ has more than one component.

Given the following conditions, I do not know how I should go about setting up my proof. Would someone be able to provide some intuition?

I feel like I could use some sort of proof by contradiction but not completely sure.

Comment: Prove it by double implication. From a $k$-edge cut, show how you can construct a $k$-vertex cut, and then from a $k$-vertex cut, show how you can construct a $k$-edge cut.